# Read config files in a WPF project

Tags: c#, wpf, web-config, configuration-files

I have a WPF application. This application should read a web.config file (from a asp.net webforms project) and a myCompany.config file. 
How can I do this? Is there a easy way to handle this?

Any help would be appreciated.

thanks!

Comment: You can't use webconfigurationmanager in a wpf application unfortunately as it exists in the system.web dll, If you want to access basic info in the config file you can use XDocument (Linq to Xml etc) as the config file is plain Xml

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to use configurationmanager

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719887%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx

Comment: Thx, but how can I set the path to the configuration files with the ConfigurationManager?
The two files are on different locations.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understood correctly, you want to read config files which are stored in a specific path?

Here is the trick:

```
Configuration _userConfig;
String configFilePath = "Your path here";

//Getting the user configuration object:
//Mapping the appropriate path:
ExeConfigurationFileMap configFileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
configFileMap.ExeConfigFilename = configFilePath;
_userConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

And there you go, `_userConfig` will contain the details in the path you specified :)

Comment: I prefer the approach of including them in the web.config noted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061999/adding-a-custom-configuration-file-in-c-application

Comment: It works, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx

Comment: As a matter of fact, I used this process with an `App.config` file, in a WPF/C# application. I can't ensure it is actually working with a `web.config`, you might prefer using Kaido's way. My aim in using this code-oriented way is to resolve path dynamically (each user has a config file in a folder stored in one of his environment variables). If you have a constant path, you might wanna consider another alternative, but this one works fine anyway with a `App.config`